# How to use reCaptcha with Java (not Android, not Web)?

Tags: java, recaptcha

How to use reCaptcha with Java (not Android, not Web)?

There are documentations on using Recaptcha with Android and web. How about plain Java SE? The purpose is that the Java App calls a method on server side. The server side needs to make sure the call is made by human.

Comment: *Java App calls a method on server side* != *made by human*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the best way to do this is going to be to use a web browser.   That is what reCAPTCHA is designed to support.

CAPTCHA / reCAPTCHA schemes present a "challenge" to the user in the form of an image or a sound file and get the user to answer a question about it.  To do this in Java, you need to be able to display the image or play the sound file, and then capture the user's response.  The response is then sent to the remote reCAPTCHA engine which checks it and  responds with a token.  The token is then sent to *your* server as a request parameter.

Now, in theory, you *could* do all of the above in a Java app (implemented in Swing or JavaFX or ...).  But you would have to:

1. reverse engineer the reCAPTCHA interactions in a Javascript reCAPTCHA (for example),
2. implement the Java UI code, and
3. integrate that with your client code so that the relevant reCAPTCHA tokens can be passed to your API ... as the proof that the user is human.

I would probably<sup>1</sup> implement this as a private web page to do the user / reCAPTCHA.  The webpage would display the reCAPTCHA token on the screen.  Then the user would need to copy-and-paste the token into an environment variable, or a command line option when making the API call.  Naturally, the token would need to time out, and you would be relying on trust to stop users from doing robot-like things using their tokens.

---

<sup>1 - Assuming that I had been chained to a computer, and starved into submission.</sup>